# Angular momentum in different points

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, conservation-laws

I have a question about angular momentum:
Is it possible to have a system where angular momentum is conserved relative to 1 point,but not conserved relative to another?

Answer (score 5):

Consider central-force motion, such as a planet moving around a (very massive) star.  The angular momentum of such a planet is constant if we take the origin as the center of the star.  It is not constant if we take the origin to be any other point.

Comment: But "constant" is different from "conserved." In the new system, there is a torque on the planet about any other point, so the torque is providing the change of the angular momentum. That torque-time integral is part of the conservation law.

Comment: @BillN:  If you're defining angular momentum to be conserved whenever $\Delta \mathbf{L} = \int \pmb{\tau} \, dt$, then I'm pretty sure that the statement "angular momentum is conserved" is tautological.

Comment: @BillN How do you define "conserved"?

Comment: @BillN If you are considering your system to only involve one body, then constant and conserved are the same thing. If your system involved more than one body, then obviously you can have each body's angular momentum change as long as the total is constant. Since this post only focuses on the system being one body, I don't think there is an issue here.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I don't know why you think that is tautological.  Conservation laws, in the Noether sense, involve a current of some type. $\Delta L$ for an object or a larger system is that current. Angular momentum is transfered from one object to another, but is never created nor destroyed, at least according to the current theories of physics.  Mass isn't conserved (consider electron-positron annihilation), but energy is.

Comment: @FGSUZ Conserved means that the quantity is neither created nor destroyed, but changes for a system or object can be accounted for via a current, basically a continuity equation.  Consider a collision between two objects which are not subjected to forces arising from interactions with other objects. Momentum of object 1 is conserved but not constant. Some of the momentum is transferred to object 2 (or vice versa). We call that transfer an impulse, a.k.a., a momentum current. The momentum of the the two object system remains constant. No creation nor destruction of momentum.

Comment: @AaronStevens No conserved is not the same as constant, for a one body system. See my example of the two-body system isolated. Maybe you meant a one-body, totally isolated system. In that case, there is no force on the one body to transfer momentum to or from the body.  Regarding the system in the question, it is about two bodies: a planet and a star. The planet won't orbit without the gravitation of the star.

Comment: @BillN What you define as your system is subjective. If I want to consider the system to just be the single planet and the star to be external to my system, then if the planet loses angular momentum to the star I would still say that angular momentum is not conserved within my system, even though I can still account for it all in a larger system. When you only have one angular momentum to consider for your system, conserved and constant are in fact the same thing.

Comment: @BillN Okay, I see your point, but I'm sorry to disagree, or not disagree, but just not joining your view. For me, they'll keep being the same, but I'll be very careful to clarify this point from now on. Let me explain my view: I only say "conserved" when talking about "total" amounts. So total momentum is conserved because it is constant. I never use "conserved" with partial systems, because saying "momentum 1 is conserved but not constant" is like "okay, it's not a random number, but it's still unspecified", so it's not useful for me. Hope you understand.

Comment: @AaronStevens Your last sentence: "When you only have one angular momentum to consider for your system, conserved and constant are in fact the same thing." Agreed, but non-constant doesn't mean non-conserved.  Non-constant simply means angular momentum has moved between my system and another system. Nothing creates angular momentum. It must  be constant, and conservation laws involve continuity relationships.

Comment: @FGSUZ My main point is that non-constant doesn't mean non-conserved when it comes to momentum, angular momentum, energy, and charge. How are you defining a "system?" Is it necessarily disconnected from everything else in the universe?

Comment: @BillN We are just using different definitions of what it means for something to be conserved within a system, but we agree on a deeper level. I agree with you within your definition, which I don't think is necessarily wrong. Thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to have a system where angular momentum is conserved relative to 1 point,but not conserved relative to another?

Total angular momentum will be conserved but the angular momentum of any part of the system will have a value dependent on where you take your base point.

Answer (score 3):

Angular momentum relative to an origin ${\mathcal O_1}$

$$ \mathbf{L_{\mathcal O_1}} = \mathbf{r_{\mathcal O_1} \times p_{\mathcal O_1}}$$

where $\mathbf r_{\mathcal O_1}$ is the position vector to the particle relative to some origin ${\mathcal O_1}$. 
Now suppose that angular momentum is conserved in ${\mathcal O_1}$. Then

$$ \frac{d \mathbf L_1}{dt} = \mathbf{\dot{r_1} \times p_1} + \mathbf{r_1 \times \dot{p_1}} = \frac{1}{m} \mathbf{p_1 \times p_1} + \mathbf{r_1 \times \dot{p_1}} =0 $$

but since the direction of momentum is frame-independent, the first term vanishes (that is, $\mathbf{p_1} = \mathbf{p}$). It then follows that

$$ \mathbf{r_1 \times F_1} =0 . $$

Now, let's look at some other origin $\mathcal{O}_2$, **given that $L$ is conserved in $\mathcal O_1$**.  Well the first term much vanish again, that's fine but what about the second term? Does

$$\mathbf{r_2 \times F_2} \stackrel{?}{=}0. $$

Well, no not necessarily. Namely, just choose an origin in which the force is perpendicular to your position vector.